# how to configure my netgear FVS318 ProSafe VPN firewall router to support a home vpn

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I have a NetGear FVS318 ProSafe VPN Firewall router. I want to configure it to support my home vpn. I have configured a Windows 7 laptop as server (incomming connection). I also have a client machine ready to use. now it is time to configure the router.

after logged on to the router, I found it is different with shows found online. There is nowhere I can find a PPTP port forwarding. And its built-in VPN Settings is more than I can understand.

Anybody can help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per the official manual from [here](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/FVS318v3_RM_11Jan2012.pdf), at page 3-6 there is an example for port forward to an web server.  You may just follow it but change to accept port traffics for 1723 and 47.

Update: Please try the following,

1) At the left menu, choose **Add Service**, then **Add a Custom Service**, now put the name as **PPTP**, protocol **TCP**, port start and port end should be 1723

2) Do the same for port 47 and the name should be **GRE**

3) At the left menu, choose **Ports**, then choose **Add Inbound services**

4) ALLOW always both PPTP and GRE to your PPTP Server IP

Now you can test your PPTP connection.

Comment: Yes, you are right but that only support TCP and UDP. there is no option for PPTP there. we have to use PPTP there?

Comment: I assume that you have a FVS318 V1 device, did you upgrade the firmware to v2.4?

Comment: Thank you for your help. you are right. Mine is still v1.4. I got the v2.4 but it always tell me "Upload Data Error.... Please make sure your file is correct!!!". I downloaded twice and tried several times.

Comment: I just reset to default. I still get the same error.

Comment: finally I successfully upgraded to v2.4 but there is no big changes in the settings. there is still no support on PPTP.

Comment: @peterboston Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, hkdtam. I have done you suggested. It seems there is a barrier somewhere in between. I am seeking help here [link](http://superuser.com/questions/1087107/vpn-failed-at-registering-your-computer-on-the-network-stage?noredirect=1#comment1538714_1087107).