# vpn failed at Registering your computer on the network stage

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I am setting vpn with Windows 7 machine without any 3rd party software. It is failed at the registering your computer on the network stage. What is the issue could be?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: are you connecting to a domain, using domain credentials?

Comment: I followed the instruction here [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/) and here [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/134046/how-to-connect-to-a-vpn-in-windows/) for my Windows 7 machines. I don't think there is a domain involved.